# React native Gesture Detector and Animated.View error 'Value is undefined, expected an Object'

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I was designing an app and tried to make a bottom sheet. I used 'Animated.View' inside 'Gesture Detector' and I am getting error **'Value is undefined, expected an Object'**.

The code is this

```
import {Dimensions, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {Gesture, GestureDetector} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
export const BottomSheet = () => {
    const transalateY = useSharedValue(0);
  const gesture = Gesture.Pan().onUpdate(event => {
    transalateY.value = event.translationY;
  });

  const rBottomSheetStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
        transform: [{translateY: transalateY.value}]
    }
  })

  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
      <Animated.View style={[anStyle.anContainer, rBottomSheetStyle]}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 4,
            width: 75,
            backgroundColor: '#6D6D6D',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            marginTop: 10,
            borderRadius: 10,
          }}></View>
      </Animated.View>
    </GestureDetector>
  );
};

const anStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  anContainer: {
    height: height,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    elevation: 20,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: height / 1.5,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
});
```

dependecies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.7.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.12"
  },
```

These all are the things in my code. I don't know what is the issue. I tried downgrading upgrading the reanimated packages and still not resolved. Please help me with the suitable answer and let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: I have created an example which works (at least for iOS) https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/animation-actionsheet
I cannot recognize something wrong.

Comment: this code for android its not working..the bottom sheet is not moving @MichaelBahl

Comment: Wrap the view with GestureHandlerRootView (I updated my example)

Comment: it works there..then why not my code :(

Comment: noice it somehow worked when I downgraded and upgraded packages